# RHEL Chrony no output

Tags: synchronization, rhel, ntp, chrony

I am trying to run chrony in my RHEL system. I got ntpd working, but I want higher resolution/accuracy.

I have been following these steps https://www.tecmint.com/install-chrony-in-centos-ubuntu-linux/.
I've successfully edited the conf file as well as started chrony, but when I try to check everything, I get no outputs. Does anyone know why this is happening and know how to fix this?

[image: ChronyIssue]

Comment: Questions about operating systems, their utilities, networking and hardware, are off topic here. [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Please delete this and ask, instead, on https://unix.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

It appears the issue was that I had Selinux not disabled.

Comment: Also, if you need SELinux enabled, it appears you can just add an "|cat" to get it to work
https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1574418